# How to deal with possible non-terminals?

Tags: java, grammar, ebnf

Let's say I had an EBNF like this:

```
<Expr> -> <Term> {( + | - ) <Term>}
```

The {} brackets mean choose zero or more, so how would I know when I have just `<Term>` vs something like `<Term> + <Term> + <Term>` when I'm reading the line character by character?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a recursive descent parser, what you want to do is **look ahead** one token. If you've just read a `<Term>` and the next token is `+` or `-` then you follow this production. If it's not, then this `<Expr>` production is complete and you return to the caller.

To implement this in code, you want something like a global `lookaheadToken` variable. You can use that token to make decisions on how to proceed with parsing before you actually commit to a particular production and *consume* the token.